# Php Pthreads extension is enabled in Wamp settings window, but does not appear in Loaded Extensions in Localhost (Windows)

Tags: php, windows, pthreads, wamp

There are many similar explanations about this topic, but none solved my problem. I have followed the installation guide of php Pthreads at: http://php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php

After that extension was showing at wampserver settings window:

[image]

Howerver, it did not appear in loaded extensions in localhost. I have checked the logs and saw the error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pthreads: Unable to initialize module
>   Module compiled with module API=20121212
>   PHP compiled with module API=20131226
>   These options need to match  in Unknown on line 0

I have searched for the error. Some explanations said to download the correct version of "Pthreads". I have tried several versions and now I  get another error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/php_pthreads.dll' - ï¿½ï¿½
>   ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½.
>   in Unknown on line 0

Both "php.ini" files in Apache folder and Php folder have the lines:

```
extension=php_pthreads.dll 
extension_dir ="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/"
```

Currently I get this error and extension is not loaded. What can be done here? Thank you

Comment: So which versions are you using of 1) WAMPServer 2)Apache 3)PHP Also which version of `pthreads` did you download?

Comment: 1) WAMPServer 3.0.6 
2) Apache 2.4.23
3) PHP 5.6.25
4) Pthreads 3.0.6

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like pthreads 3.0.6 is built only for PHP7.

As I see you are using PHP5.6.25 then the last version of pthreads that will work on that PHP is V2.0.9

Downloadable [from here](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/2.0.9/)

Comment: Yes! That works. Thank you, I did not think there is such strict version matching rules. These version matching rules should be written somewhere in their Readme or something.

Comment: They are, but you have to read them. Look in the unziped files for `README.MD`

Comment: Also as a general rule any major release of PHP has the possbility to change the way it interfaces to extensions and Apache. Also each time the PHP & Apache groups change the C/C++ compiler they use can also mean you need to look for extensions that are also compiled with the same compiler as PHP is compiled with. Your issue was a compiler mismatch and a PHP version mismatch

Comment: Also you installed a WebServer and a DBMS which means you took on the roles of `Web Site Admin` & `Server Admin` & `System Admin` & `Database Admin` & `Tech Support` & `Lead Developer` and a few other roles. Each of which would normally be done by a different person or even a team of people. **Lots to learn**

Comment: Yes, this looked as the easiest way to develop a small Php project